# Polyglot Language Picker 2 - changing the default language after selection

Tags: php, jquery

I'm utilising the above ([PolyGlot Language Selecter 2](http://www.ixtendo.com/polyglot-language-switcher-2/))

And whilst it works incredibly well - I'm having a problem setting the default language.

Does anyone know how to change the display of the default language **after** a selection?

http://ixtendo.com/demo/polyglot-language-switcher-2/jquery-demo.html#

You can see the demo on the website - basically, no matter what I do, whenever I choose another language - English (US) is **still** shown as the default.

I have tried using jQuery to add and remove the class as well as only apply the class 'pls-selected-locale' using the language from the URL which is stored in a session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ascertained that this can be configued via the following (using jQuery approach and not via HTML)

```
$('html').attr('lang','[language]');
```

Where `[language]` equals an accepted `'data-lang-id'`

For example, to set to Czech:

```
$('html').attr('lang','cz_CZ');
```

For myself, I was able to store a users language within a session and then apply that as follows:

```
selectedLang: function () {
    if($("#lang").val()==='Czech'){
        $('html').attr('lang','cz_CZ');
    }
```